# Is my use of inheritance and extended stereotype correct in this Use Case

Tags: uml

The use case should depict this situation:

A shipman can ask questions via radio to either a VL, DM or WL. Depending on the question, they need to look it up in APIC (a software tool), but this is not always the case. They all are apic operators, but depending on their role, they have their speciality that they only can access in apic.

The question the shipman asks can be about lock executions, the nautical weather, etc... but it all comes down to the same question-answer format.

Is my use case correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three issues here:

- The extends arrow is the wrong way around.
- Generalizations of UCs is a bad idea in general.
- Just as a side note: your actors miss their legs. This way it's a Female symbol (Venus' mirror).

Let's elaborate a bit on the 2nd. Why is it a bad idea? UCs represent a single added value for an actor a system under consideration will deliver. So each UC is unique (think of unique sales propositions). Generalization of USP is only valid in a franchise. So unless you model McDonalds here, it's likely a wrong approach. Look at the main UC "ask question". Do you consider that added value from a system? I wouldn't. When looking at the bubbles behind they more look like primary use cases. So, just remove that general "ask question" and connect the bubbles behind directly with `Shipman`.

---

As always when it comes to UC questions: Bittner/Spence about UC is the best read I can recommend.

Comment: So the extends arrow should always point to the use case bubble it extends? What do you mean by USP by the way? Thanks for the recommendations! I will be sure to add them to my reading list.

Comment: USP = unique sales proposition (Google is your friend...) And yes, the `extends` points FROM the extending while  `include` points TO the including UC.

Answer (score 1):

Asking a question is usually not a use case. The goal of the shipman is probably not to ask a question, but to get some answers. So asking and anwering is one use case.

When analysing the use case, several possibilities will show up, such as looking up information in the APICS-system. I would just describe this within the use case (possibly with an Activity Diagram). What is the advantage of using an extend here? (I agree with the other answer, that the arrow is in the wrong direction. Additionally it should be an open arrow).

Each goal is an own use case, even when they have much in common. After describing the essential steps of the use cases, it may save some work to look at them and find those that have a big overlap in the essential steps and then create an abstract use case containing the commonalities. But this should only be done *after* describing the use cases.

Always remember, that the main goal of use case analysis is to find all functional requirements for the system, especially those that are not immediately obvious. If your use cases are just wrappers of functions you already know, not much insight is gained by them.

Comment: I very much agree with your advice on the use of use case generalizations. Sometimes, they are very useful.